# Python2.7.8 Script to print all files in a directory path. Please help fix

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python.

I am working on a script to ask a user for a directory path. Once provided,
I would like the script to list all files in the directory excluding any sub directories.

Here is what I have so far. I seem to be stuck trying to find a way to test to see if the item in question is a directory or a file. Please help.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os

dir_f = raw_input(" Plese enter directory path where you would like to have \
the files renamed \n" )

#print dir_f

os.chdir(dir_f)

#prints items in directory one line at a time. TEST section

while os.listdir(dir_f):
    if os.path.isdir(dir_f):
        continue
    else:
        print "\n".join(os.listdir(dir_f)) 

    # os.rename(src, dst) dont use this yet.
```

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop to me, good sir or ma'am.

Comment: What is the output of this program, and how does it differ from what you *want* it to output? Without that I can only guess at your intentions, but `while os.listdir(dir_f)` will loop forever; likely you meant `for item in os.listdir(dir_f)` or something like that.

Comment: oh, yeah. my script is definitely broken. How did you spot the infinite loop so fast? My amateur eyes do not see it. However, I know it is because I've run it. I was expecting that it would list all files in a directory and stop when It has nothing else to list?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25630948/20789) for how to use a `for` loop to iterate through a list, and read [the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) for a good explanation of how/why to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple code you can try, and them integrate to your needs.

```
import os

folder = '/tmp/test'

for item in os.listdir('/tmp/test'):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder,item)):
         print item
```

Comment: user3655020, This version prints items in the folder that are **not** themselves subdirectories. If that is what you wanted, great, but your  original question does not make that clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I **think** it does what you intend. Two important changes:

1. I used a `for` loop instead of `while` ([read up on how this works](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)!)

   - (A `for` loop is, in general, the correct way to iterate through a list or collection of objects in Python.)
2. Your version clearly missed the `not` in `if not os.path.isdir(...)`; your version was treating non-directories as directories, and vice versa

Code (**edited to include explanatory messages about what it's finding**):

```
import os, os.path

dir_f = raw_input(" Plese enter directory path where you would like to have \
the files renamed \n" )

#print dir_f

os.chdir(dir_f)

#prints items in directory one line at a time. TEST section

for item in os.listdir(dir_f):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_f,item)):
        print "this is not a directory: ", item
    else:
        print "this is a subdirectory: ", item
        print "... and it contains: ", ','.join(os.listdir(os.path.join(dir_f,item)))

    # os.rename(src, dst) dont use this yet.
```

Comment: Hi Dan! I don't know why, but your script has some bizarre results. when I run it on my targeted directory it does not return the empty test files. When I go one directory above, it returns both the directory and files. I went over your code, and to my virgin coding eyes, every thing looks fine. I'm lost.

Comment: Again, without understanding exactly your intentions it's hard to know how its behavior differs from what you expect. This version loops through the parent directory (`dir_f`) and **ignores** files therein, **except** for subdirectories; for the subdirectories it prints their contents. I'll make this a little more explicit...

Answer (score -1):

Here is my script with the changes suggested by Lovato

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os 





dir_f = raw_input(" Plese enter directory path where you would like to have \
the files renamed \n" )

#print dir_f

os.chdir(dir_f)


for item in os.listdir(dir_f):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_f,item)):
                         print item
```

Comment: You should be editing your original post, rather than post this as an answer! This doesn't help us understand your problem, though, because it doesn't clarify what you were actually **trying** to do.

Comment: Dan you need to visit the state of Washington and smoke a joint. :P, j/k. Okay, Dan I will be more descriptive in the future. I will also edit my original post when there is a request for clarity.